# Simple LINQ Order by not working

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new with LINQ. I'm using this function:

```
public IEnumerable<Vendedores> GetVendedores()
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {
            Vendedores _allvendors= new Vendedores();
            _allvendors.Nombre = "All Vendors";
            _allvendors.ID_Vendedor = -1;
            var query = context.Vendedores;
            var _vendors= query.Where(f => f.Activo == true).OrderBy(o=>Nombre).ToList();                                    
            _vendors.Insert(0, _allvendors);
            return _vendors;
        }
    }
```

It should give me order list of active vendors. The where part work fine, but the order is ignored and the records after the .ToList are in the original table order. What i'm i doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: `.OrderBy(o=> o.Nombre)` Notice the `o.` before `Nombre`. I'm sure the lambda doesnt know what the `Nombre` property is without its class.

Comment: I'm guessing that `Nombre` is a property on `this`, so they're all ordered by the same value. Which (given a stable sort, which LINQ has) is the same as not sorting at all.

Comment: did you declare Nombre elsewhere ? it shouldn't compile like that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need `o.Nombre` instead of `Nombre`

```
var _vendors = query
              .Where(f => f.Activo)
              .OrderBy(o=> o.Nombre)
              .ToList();
```

Also `f => f.Activo == true` can be written as  `f => f.Activo`.

Comment: Excelent! what a fool of me! Strange compiler won't show me this.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

it should be this way:

```
var _vendors= query.Where(f => f.Activo == true).OrderBy(o=>o.Nombre).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes! i misss the "o." before Nombre field. Thanks!

Comment: welcome and glad it helped, sometime it happens we miss a small thing and keep thinking whats the wrong..:)